# MvcSiteMapProvider modifies Routevalue

Tags: url, model-view-controller

I'm trying to set a `RouteValues` on a `ParrentNode` But when it "modifies" my url parameter.

It should look like: /Forum/Category/Announcements_5

But it's written like: /Forum/Category/Announcements%0D%0A5

```
var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;

        if (node != null && node.ParentNode != null)
        {
            node.Title = GetPostID[0].Replace("-", " ");
            node.ParentNode.Title = GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Title;
            string url = GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Title + GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Id;
            node.ParentNode.RouteValues.Add("id", url);
        }
```

How can I fix the problem so i can write the url corrently.

I tried with `Replace("%0D%0A","_")` but it didnt work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to add `.Trim()` to your code as below.

```
var node = SiteMaps.Current.CurrentNode;

        if (node != null && node.ParentNode != null)
        {
            node.Title = GetPostID[0].Replace("-", " ");
            node.ParentNode.Title = GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Title;
            string url = GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Title.Trim() + GetForumPost.ForumSubCategory.Id;
            node.ParentNode.RouteValues.Add("id", url);
        }
```